# Este programa me imprime repetidamente lo mismo, cual de los dos for es?

Tags: c++, bucle-for

Implemente una función que me imprimiera la lista pero ahora me imprime bien pero infinitamente intento hallar el error en alguno de los dos for pero no lo veo, ya intente varias cosas con el for pero sinceramente yo no le pillo la logica, creo que depronto el error esta que la lista de obtenerEstudiantesPrestamos es infinita pero despues veo que imprime normal con el cout

hay aparte los dos for son lo que tienen un comentario diciendo aqui me imprime sin parar

Aquí dejo una parte de mi codigo

Este es int main

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include "Exception.h"
#include "Biblioteca.h"
#include "Estudiante.h"
#include "Prestamo.h"
#include "Libro.h"

using namespace std;


int main() {
    try{
    long codigoE;
    long codigoL;
    cout << "ingrese el codigo del estudante: "<<endl;
    cin>>codigoE;
    cout<<"ingrese el codigo del libro: "<<endl;
    cin>>codigoL;


    list<Libro*> * LibrosAlmacenados = new list<Libro*>();
    //long codigo, string titulo, string editorial
    LibrosAlmacenados->push_back(new Libro(15,"principe","morgan"));
    LibrosAlmacenados->push_back(new Libro(11, "azul", "roma"));
    LibrosAlmacenados->push_back(new Libro(155488, "caldo", "norma"));
    list<Estudiante*> * EstudiantesConPrestamos = new list<Estudiante*>();
    //long codigo, string nombres, string apellidos
    EstudiantesConPrestamos->push_back(new Estudiante(13,"fatima","zapata"));
    EstudiantesConPrestamos->push_back(new Estudiante(8,"pedro","azulejo"));
    EstudiantesConPrestamos->push_back(new Estudiante(125464,"castillo","alejandro"));
    //tring fechaRealizacion, Estudiante* NuevoEstudiante, Libro* LibroNuevo
    list<Prestamo*> * prestamosRealizados = new list<Prestamo*>();
    prestamosRealizados->push_back(new Prestamo("14/ 11 / 2002",new Estudiante(13,"fatima","zapata"),new Libro(15,"principe","morgan") ));
    prestamosRealizados->push_back(new Prestamo("12/ 10 / 2010",new Estudiante(13,"fatima","zapata"),new Libro(11,"azul", "roma") ));
    prestamosRealizados->push_back(new Prestamo("18/ 12 / 2009",new Estudiante(8,"pedro","azulejo"),new Libro(155488, "caldo", "norma")));
    
    
    //Estudiante* NuevoEstudiante, Libro* LibroNuevo, Prestamo* PrestamoNuevo
    Estudiante * NuevoEstudainte = new Estudiante(codigoE,"pedro","azulejo");
    Libro * LibroNuevo = new Libro(codigoL,"azul", "roma");
    Prestamo * PrestamoNuevo = new Prestamo("12 / 11/ 2004",new Estudiante(codigoE,"pedro","azulejo"),new Libro(codigoL,"azul", "roma"));
    Biblioteca * BlibiotecaNueva = new Biblioteca(NuevoEstudainte,LibroNuevo,PrestamoNuevo,prestamosRealizados,EstudiantesConPrestamos,LibrosAlmacenados);  
    
    


    try{
    cout<<"La informacion del estudiante es: \nNombre: "<<BlibiotecaNueva->buscarEstudiante(codigoE)->GetNombres()<<"\nApellidos: "<<BlibiotecaNueva->buscarEstudiante(codigoE)->GetApellidos()<<"\nCodigo: "<<BlibiotecaNueva->buscarEstudiante(codigoE)->GetCodigo()<<endl;
    cout<<"La informacion del libro es: \nCodigo: "<<BlibiotecaNueva->buscarLibro(codigoL)->GetCodigo()<<"\nTitulo: "<<BlibiotecaNueva->buscarLibro(codigoL)->GetTitulo()<<"\nEditorial: "<<BlibiotecaNueva->buscarLibro(codigoL)->GetEditorial()<<endl;

    list<Prestamo*>::iterator it;
    
    Prestamo * personaSeleccionada = NULL;
    it = BlibiotecaNueva->obtenerEstudiantesPrestamos(codigoE)->begin();
    // Usando ciclo for para iterar / recorrer una lista
    cout<<"Los prestamos realizados por el estudiante son: "<<endl;
    for (; it != BlibiotecaNueva->obtenerEstudiantesPrestamos(codigoE)->end(); it++) {
        personaSeleccionada = * it;
        cout << personaSeleccionada<<"\n";
    }

 
    }catch (Exception * exc) {
        cout << "ERROR : " << exc->GetMensaje()<<endl;
        
    }

            cout << "Fin"<<endl;
    } catch (Exception * exc) {
        cout << "ERROR : " << exc->GetMensaje();
        delete exc;
    }  
   
    
    return 0;
}
```

esta es la biblioteca.h

```
#ifndef BIBLIOTECA_H
#define BIBLIOTECA_H
#include "Estudiante.h"
#include "Libro.h"
#include "Prestamo.h"
#include <list>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Biblioteca {

private:
    Estudiante * NuevoEstudiante;
    Libro * LibroNuevo;
    Prestamo * PrestamoNuevo;
    list<Prestamo*> * prestamosRealizados;
    list<Estudiante*> * EstudiantesConPrestamos;
    list<Libro*> * LibrosAlmacenados;

public:

    Biblioteca(Estudiante* NuevoEstudiante, Libro* LibroNuevo, Prestamo* PrestamoNuevo, std::list<Prestamo*> * listasPrestamos, std::list<Estudiante*> * listaEstudiante, std::list<Libro*> * listaLibros):
    NuevoEstudiante(NuevoEstudiante), LibroNuevo(LibroNuevo), PrestamoNuevo(PrestamoNuevo),prestamosRealizados(listasPrestamos),EstudiantesConPrestamos(listaEstudiante),LibrosAlmacenados(listaLibros){}


    Libro* GetLibroNuevo() ;
    Estudiante* GetNuevoEstudiante()  ;
    Prestamo* GetPrestamoNuevo();

    
    //metodos
    Estudiante *  buscarEstudiante(long codigoE);
    Libro *  buscarLibro(long codigoL);
    list<Prestamo*> * obtenerEstudiantesPrestamos(long codigoE);

    

};

#endif /* BIBLIOTECA_H */
```

esta es la Biblioteca.cpp

```
#include "Biblioteca.h"
#include "Exception.h"
#include "Biblioteca.h"
#include <list>
#include "Estudiante.h"
#include "Prestamo.h"
#include "Libro.h"




Libro* Biblioteca::GetLibroNuevo()  {
    return LibroNuevo;
}

Estudiante* Biblioteca::GetNuevoEstudiante()  {
    return NuevoEstudiante;
}

Prestamo* Biblioteca::GetPrestamoNuevo()  {
    return PrestamoNuevo;
}

Estudiante * Biblioteca::buscarEstudiante(long codigoE){
    //    list<Prestamo*>::iterator it; tambien puedo incializar el iterador asi

    for (auto it = this->EstudiantesConPrestamos->begin(); it != this->EstudiantesConPrestamos->end(); it++)
    {
        if ((*it)->GetCodigo() == codigoE)
        {
            return *it;
        }
    }throw new Exception("No se encuentra al estudiante");
}
              
list<Prestamo*> * Biblioteca::obtenerEstudiantesPrestamos(long codigoE) {
    list<Prestamo *> * resultado = new list<Prestamo*>();
    for (auto it = this->prestamosRealizados->begin(); it != this->prestamosRealizados->end(); it++)
    {
        if ((*it)->GetNuevoEstudiante()->GetCodigo() == codigoE)
        {
            resultado->push_back(*it);
        }
    }
    return resultado;
}

/* list<Prestamo*> * Biblioteca::obtenerEstudiantesPrestamos(long codigoE) {
    list<Prestamo *> * resultado = new list<Prestamo*>();
    Prestamo * est ;
    for (auto it = this->prestamosRealizados->begin(); it != this->prestamosRealizados->end(); it++)
    {
        if (est->GetNuevoEstudiante()->GetCodigo() == codigoE)
        {
            resultado->push_back(est);
        }
    }
    return resultado;
}*/

              
Libro * Biblioteca::buscarLibro(long codigoL){
    for (auto it = this->LibrosAlmacenados->begin(); it != this->LibrosAlmacenados->end(); it++)
    {
        if ((*it)->GetCodigo() == codigoL)
        {
            return *it;
        }
    }throw new Exception("No se encuentra al libro");
}
```

este es el Estudiante.h

```
#ifndef ESTUDIANTE_H
#define ESTUDIANTE_H
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Estudiante {

private:
    long codigo;
    string nombres;
    string apellidos;
    
    
public:
    Estudiante();
    Estudiante(long codigo, string nombres, string apellidos);
    
    string GetApellidos() const ;
    
    long GetCodigo() const ;

    string GetNombres() const ;

    Estudiante(const Estudiante& orig);
    virtual ~Estudiante();

};

#endif /* ESTUDIANTE_H */
```

este es el Libro.h

```
#ifndef LIBRO_H
#define LIBRO_H

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Libro {

private:
    long codigo;
    string titulo;
    string editorial;
    
public:
    Libro();
    Libro(long codigo, string titulo, string editorial) ;
    long GetCodigo();

    string GetEditorial();

    string GetTitulo();
    Libro(const Libro& orig);
    virtual ~Libro();

};

#endif /* LIBRO_H */
```

Este es el libro.cpp

```
#include "Libro.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


Libro::Libro(long codigo, string titulo, string editorial) {
    this->codigo=codigo;
    this->titulo=titulo;
    this->editorial=editorial;
}

Libro::Libro(const Libro& orig) {
}

Libro::~Libro() {
}

long Libro::GetCodigo()  {
    return codigo;
}

string Libro::GetEditorial()  {
    return editorial;
}

string Libro::GetTitulo()  {
    return titulo;
}
```

Este es el Prestamo.h

```
#ifndef PRESTAMO_H
#define PRESTAMO_H
#include <iostream>
#include "Estudiante.h"
#include "Libro.h"
using namespace std;
class Prestamo {

private:
    string fechaRealizacion;
    Estudiante *  NuevoEstudiante;
    Libro * LibroNuevo;
public:
    Prestamo();
    Prestamo(string fechaRealizacion, Estudiante* NuevoEstudiante, Libro* LibroNuevo);
    Libro* GetLibroNuevo() const;

    Estudiante* GetNuevoEstudiante() const;

    string GetFechaRealizacion() const;


    
    Prestamo(const Prestamo& orig);
    virtual ~Prestamo();

};

#endif /* PRESTAMO_H */
```

este es el Prestamo.cpp

```
#include "Prestamo.h"
#include <cstring>

Prestamo::Prestamo(string fechaRealizacion, Estudiante* NuevoEstudiante, Libro* LibroNuevo) {
    this->fechaRealizacion=fechaRealizacion;
    if(fechaRealizacion == ""){
        cout<<"digite otra cadena esta no es valida";
    }//threw Exception("no es valido")  
    this->NuevoEstudiante=NuevoEstudiante;
    this->LibroNuevo=LibroNuevo;
}

Prestamo::Prestamo(const Prestamo& orig) {
}

Prestamo::~Prestamo() {
}

Libro* Prestamo::GetLibroNuevo() const {
    return LibroNuevo;
}

Estudiante* Prestamo::GetNuevoEstudiante() const {
    return NuevoEstudiante;
}

string Prestamo::GetFechaRealizacion() const {
    return fechaRealizacion;
}
```

Comment: ¿Puedes poner el codigo de Prestamo, Estudiante y Libro? Por otro lado, por qué poner el código entre try/catch?

Comment: eso lo hago para vereficar los valores validos, con una clase llamada excepcion que hago el llamado si depronto no se encuentra al estudiante o algo mas

Comment: Hay te pase todo el código, para ver si puedes hacer algo es lo único que me falla

Comment: [Cómo crear un ejemplo MÍNIMO, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) y recalco MÍNIMO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La respuesta es complicada porque partes de bastantes errores, tanto de diseño como de implementación. Tampoco entiendo por qué estar siempre con punteros, salvo que sea parte del trabajo pedido.

Respecto a los punteros, todos los objetos que estás creando con memoria dinámica has de destruirlos luego. Para eso están los destructores de la clase.

Pero más allá de eso, tiene un primer problema. Primero creas una especie de base de datos con estudiantes y libros. Pero cuando creas la lista de préstamos, no estás referenciando a esos estudiantes y libros creados. Es decir, metes a este estudiante en la lista de estudiantes:

```
EstudiantesConPrestamos->push_back(new Estudiante(13,"fatima","zapata"));
```

Pero luego, en la lista de préstamos, metes a otro estudiante diferente:

```
prestamosRealizados->push_back(new Prestamo("14/ 11 / 2002",new Estudiante(13,"fatima","zapata"),new Libro(15,"principe","morgan") ));
```

Este estudiante (13,"fatima","zapata") no tiene nada que ver con el de la lista de estudiantes. Como luego la biblioteca la creas a partir de una lista de estudiantes, una de libros y una de préstamos, la cosa empieza a dejar de funcionar.

Partiendo, como dije de primeras, que el diseño no es bueno, pero asumiéndolo, la forma de meter el mismo estudiante de la lista y el mismo libro de la lista, sería algo así:

```
 //introducir un estudiante por codigo:
    Estudiante* estudiante;
    for (auto it=EstudiantesConPrestamos->begin(); it!=EstudiantesConPrestamos->end(); ++it)
    {
        if ((*it)->GetCodigo() == 13)
        {
            estudiante = *it;
            break;
        }
    }
    //introducir un libro por codigo:
    Libro* libro;
    for (auto it=LibrosAlmacenados->begin(); it!=LibrosAlmacenados->end(); it++)
    {
        if ((*it)->GetCodigo() == 15)
        {
            libro = *it;
            break;
        }
    }
    prestamosRealizados->push_back(new Prestamo("20/ 11 / 2002",estudiante,libro));
```

Si luego quieres meter otro libro, pues igual:

```
 //introduzco otro libro
    for (auto it=LibrosAlmacenados->begin(); it!=LibrosAlmacenados->end(); it++)
    {
        if ((*it)->GetCodigo() == 11)
        {
            libro = *it;
            break;
        }
    }
    prestamosRealizados->push_back(new Prestamo("20/ 11 / 2002",estudiante,libro));
```

Fíjate que he metido en la lista de préstamos al mismo estudiante con otro libro. Ahora tendremos dos libros a cargo del estudiante.

Con la Biblioteca tienes otro problema de diseño. No puedes crear una biblioteca con usarios concretos. La Biblioteca, en todo caso, funcionará con la lista de libros, de estudiantes, y de préstamos que relacionen a los dos primeros (que tampoco, pero bueno...por no alejarnos mucho del diseño original).

Así que te propongo un constructor así en la clase Biblioteca:

**biblioteca.h**

Biblioteca(std::list<Prestamo*> * listasPrestamos, std::list<Estudiante*> * listaEstudiante, std::list<Libro*> * listaLibros);

**biblioteca.cpp**

```
Biblioteca::Biblioteca(std::list<Prestamo*> * listasPrestamos, std::list<Estudiante*> * listaEstudiante, std::list<Libro*> * listaLibros):
        prestamosRealizados(listasPrestamos), EstudiantesConPrestamos(listaEstudiante), LibrosAlmacenados(listaLibros){}
```

Por último, el método para devolver los libros leídos por cada estudiante, pues lo más rápido es crear un método que lea la lista desde la misma clase (no es nada correcto, pero es lo más fácil):

**biblioteca.h**

void obtenerEstudiantesPrestamos(long codigoE);

**biblioteca.cpp**

```
void Biblioteca::obtenerEstudiantesPrestamos(long codigoE)
{
for (auto it = this->prestamosRealizados->begin(); it != this->prestamosRealizados->end(); it++)
    {
        if ((*it)->GetNuevoEstudiante()->GetCodigo()==codigoE)
        {
            cout<<(*it)->GetLibroNuevo()->GetTitulo()<<endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Con todo esto, en **main.cpp**

```
int main()
{
    //Creo la "base de datos" de estudiantes y libros
    list<Libro*> * LibrosAlmacenados = new list<Libro*>();
    //long codigo, string titulo, string editorial
    LibrosAlmacenados->push_back(new Libro(15,"principe","morgan"));
    LibrosAlmacenados->push_back(new Libro(11, "azul", "roma"));
    LibrosAlmacenados->push_back(new Libro(155488, "caldo", "norma"));
    list<Estudiante*> * EstudiantesConPrestamos = new list<Estudiante*>();
    //long codigo, string nombres, string apellidos
    EstudiantesConPrestamos->push_back(new Estudiante(13,"fatima","zapata"));
    EstudiantesConPrestamos->push_back(new Estudiante(8,"pedro","azulejo"));
    EstudiantesConPrestamos->push_back(new Estudiante(125464,"castillo","alejandro"));

    list<Prestamo*> * prestamosRealizados = new list<Prestamo*>();

    //introducir un estudiante por codigo:
    Estudiante* estudiante;
    for (auto it=EstudiantesConPrestamos->begin(); it!=EstudiantesConPrestamos->end(); ++it)
    {
        if ((*it)->GetCodigo() == 13)
        {
            estudiante = *it;
            break;
        }
    }
    //introducir un libro por codigo:
    Libro* libro;
    for (auto it=LibrosAlmacenados->begin(); it!=LibrosAlmacenados->end(); it++)
    {
        if ((*it)->GetCodigo() == 15)
        {
            libro = *it;
            break;
        }
    }
    prestamosRealizados->push_back(new Prestamo("20/ 11 / 2002",estudiante,libro));
    //introduzco otro libro
    for (auto it=LibrosAlmacenados->begin(); it!=LibrosAlmacenados->end(); it++)
    {
        if ((*it)->GetCodigo() == 11)
        {
            libro = *it;
            break;
        }
    }
    prestamosRealizados->push_back(new Prestamo("20/ 12 / 2002",estudiante,libro));
    //creo la biblioteca
    Biblioteca * BlibiotecaNueva = new Biblioteca(prestamosRealizados,EstudiantesConPrestamos,LibrosAlmacenados);
    //Ahora busco un dato
    long codigoE;
    long codigoL;
    cout << "ingrese el codigo del estudante: "<<endl;
    cin>>codigoE;
    cout<<"ingrese el codigo del libro: "<<endl;
    cin>>codigoL;

    cout<<"La informacion del estudiante es: "<<"\nNombre: "<<BlibiotecaNueva->buscarEstudiante(codigoE)->GetNombres()<<"\nApellidos: "<<
        BlibiotecaNueva->buscarEstudiante(codigoE)->GetApellidos()<<"\nCodigo: "<<BlibiotecaNueva->buscarEstudiante(codigoE)->GetCodigo()<<endl;

    // Usando ciclo for para iterar / recorrer una lista
    cout<<"Los prestamos realizados por el estudiante son: "<<endl;
    BlibiotecaNueva->obtenerEstudiantesPrestamos(codigoE);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ya con eso me queda claro, al parecer me falta aprender mas sobre lista, gracias de nuevo me estas ayudando a comprender mi código y los errores